# Powershell GUI for various scripts to be executed

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I have a list of Powershell scripts that perform various functions 
im trying to see how i can create a GUI using those scripts .

Say like i have :

1. Button 1 : Disk Cleanup
2. Button 2 : Copy Files ( Should have a source and destination path being taken from Edit Box : meaning paths can be provided in the Text box and my scripts to take the values from that path to execute)
3. Button 3 : Clear History

I'm trying to use the New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button but unable to get the button to execute the script and even if it does execute first script its failing to execute second one .
Has anyone implemented this type of feature earlier ?

Comment: Anytime somebody says that they're trying to make a GUI I point them towards [FoxDeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238413/foxdeploy)'s guide that taught me so much. Check it out here: https://foxdeploy.com/series/learning-gui-toolmaking-series/

Comment: Try [PoshGUI](https://poshgui.com/) for easy GUI building.

Comment: To add to the list. [PoshTools](https://poshtools.com/2018/12/20/standalone-powershell-windows-form-designer-integrated-into-visual-studio-code/) now does GUI in VSCode. There's also Sapien's [PowerShellStudio](https://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio).